# How to replace a field value with the result of a concat in mysql

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update, concatenation

I have searched for a good half hour for the answer, hopefully someone can help.

I need a way of replacing a field value with a concatenated string, but also finding based on a concatenated string.

I have the following and it is not working correctly:

```
SET @current_local_url:='abc';
SET @new_local_url:='def';
update language_definitions set `value` = replace(`value`, CONCAT('/',@current_local_url,'/'), CONCAT('/',@new_local_url,'/'));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it should work. Can you show examples of the data, what you expect to get, and what you're getting instead?

Comment: *How* is it working? "not correctly" is a bit broad. Also, it would help if you would have an example of what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: If you could make a sqlfiddle to demonstrate it, that would be helpful , too.